# Gary Fisher 09 Cobia - Handlebar Upgrade

Tags: handlebars

So I bought this bike used, and it has incredibly narrow handlebars.  I don't like the feeling of things being so tight, and I'm looking to replace them.  Also, I think my bike fit is a little off (I put too much weight on the bars), so I'm looking for something that'll bring up my hand position as well.

What suggestions do you have?

Answer (score 1):

I think any kind of riser bar should help you out, but what you end up with is going to be highly dependent on your budget and riding style.  You can easily spend over a hundred bucks on a pair of handlebars.

You'll also need to find the diameter of current bars, to ensure the new ones fit your stem.  Yours should be either 25.4 or 31.8 mm (more likely 31.8 for recent builds).  I suspect you'll find a lot more riser bars available in the 31.8mm size.

If 20mm rise is sufficient and you have a 31.8 mm stem, these are on [sale](http://www.jensonusa.com/Race-Face-Atlas-AM-Handlebar-OE-1).  I'm currently riding crank brothers' [cobalt 3](http://crankbrothers.com/bars_cobalt3.php) bars that only have a 15mm rise but they are perfect for me.  I have friends who swear by Easton's [monkey bars](http://www.eastoncycling.com/en-us/mountain/products/bars/all-mountain/) like the EA50/70 as well - these are available with 20-40 mm of rise.